# How can i open thickbox in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, thickbox

I need to open thickbox in codeigniter inside controller or model. 
How to write there inside controller or model.

the result will be coming from model, so i need to show the result in the thickbox like that. Please suggest any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller:
     if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
class Thickbox extends CI_Controller {



    public function __construct() {



        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');

        //load ci url helper

    }



    public function index()

    {

        $this->load->view('thickbox_view');

        //load views 

    }

}



/* End of file thickbox.php */

/* Location: ./application/controllers/thickbox.php */
```

view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox.js"></script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">

@import "css/thickbox.css";

</style>

</head>



<body>

<a href="/images/single.jpg" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox"><img src="/images/single_t.jpg" alt="Single Image"/></a>

</body>

</html>
```

for more information visit: bugphp.com or click here [Implement ThickBox in Codeigniter](http://bugphp.com/php-tutorial/thickbox-codeigniter/%22Implement%20ThickBox%20in%20Codeigniter%22)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the Above will open view page only and if we click the image in that page, that will open in thick box know.. But i expect the result to be open in thickbox (without clicking)..

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn and understand MVC first.
You can't "open" it in model or controller, you should do this in your view.
In model you load the data, in controller you asign it and in view, you will "echo" the data.
But this is really simple thing and has nothing to do with codeigniter (it is the same like in ordinary php and/or html).
Maybe you can show us your code what have you done so far.